# Trying to send email through PHP using an email address that is configured on Microsoft's SMTP servers (@live.com, @outlook.com, etc.)

Tags: php, html, email, smtp

I'm trying to send email via a PHP script.  Here's the line of code that is supposed to send the email:

`mail($owner_email, $subject, $messageBody, $headers)`

Here are what my variables are set to:

`$owner_email` = `mike@mikemarks.net`

`$subject` = "Blah"

`$messageBody` = "Blah"

The email address, `mike@mikemarks.net`, is configured on Microsoft's email servers.  I have email sending and receiving from their servers - smtp.live.com (for outgoing).  For some reason, the above line of code isn't sending an email to `mike@mikemarks.net`.

**QUESTIONS**:

1. Are there certain email services that won't work with PHP's email
   functionality, such as Microsoft's?
2. I understand I can't set SMTP
       settings in PHP - does this mean that PHP uses its own SMTP server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP uses the SMTP server specified in the php.ini. Most often, it's localhost, which uses the hosting server's own SMTP server. Check the response of the mail function (true/false) to make sure that the email is going through, and check the mail log of the server to see if there's an error there. You can see http://www.phpclasses.org/blog/package/9/post/1-Sending-email-using-SMTP-servers-of-Gmail-Hotmail-or-Yahoo-with-PHP.html for information how to use Hotmail as the SMTP server.

Answer (score 1):

No. PHP does not have its own smtp server. It either uses the system default one (unix-ish systems) or the one configured via the smtp_* .ini directives (Windows).

If you're on a unixish host and want to use external SMTP servers, then you'll have to either use a real library, e.g. phpmailer or swiftmailer, to connect directly to the external servers. Or you configure the local smtp server to act as a forwarding-only server which passes any local-sent emails directly to the external ones.