# How to make a functional PHP contact form that sends email to @outlook.com account on a website that is going to be published on ftp server?

Tags: php, email, ftp, smtp

I am building a website that has a php contact form that will send an email on @outlook.com address. Website will be published on ftp server, but till then I published it on this free one https://www.000webhost.com/ so I can test contact form but it is not working. I've read somewhere that php mail() function does not work with smtp so I tried using PHPMailer as I found in some suggestions here ([Trying to send email through PHP using an email address that is configured on Microsoft's SMTP servers (@live.com, @outlook.com, etc.)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17975204/trying-to-send-email-through-php-using-an-email-address-that-is-configured-on-mi)) but it's also not working or maybe I'm not doing it correctly since I don't quite understand it. The code is written without using PHPMailer:

**PHP:**

```
<?php
if ($_POST["submit"]) {
    if (!$_POST['name']) {
        $error="<br />Please enter your name";
    }
    if (!$_POST['email']) {
        $error.="<br />Please enter your email address";
    }

    if (!$_POST['message']) {
        $error.="<br />Please enter a message";
    }
    if ($_POST['email']!="" AND !filter_var($_POST['email'],FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        $error.="<br />Please enter a valid email address";
    }
    if ($error) {
        $result='<div class="alert alert-danger"><strong>There were error(s)in your form:</strong>'.$error.'</div>';
    } else {
        if (mail("mymail@outlook.com", "message from website!", "Name: ".$_POST['name']."Email: ".$_POST['email']."message: ".$_POST['message'])) {
            $result='<div class="alert alert-success"><strong>Thank you!</strong> I\'ll be in touch.</div>';
        } else {
            $result='<div class="alert alert-danger">Sorry, there was an error sending your message. Please try again later.</div>';
        }
    } 
} 
?>
```

**HTML:**

```
<div>
<?php echo $result; ?>
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data ">
    <div class="form-group ">
        <label><h3>Your name:</h3></label>
            <input name="name" type="text " id="exampleInputName" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" value="<?php echo $_POST['name']; ?>">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group ">
        <label><h3>Your e-mail:</h3></label>
        <input name="email" type="email " id="exampleInputEmail" class="form-control" placeholder="name@email.com" value="<?php echo $_POST['email']; ?>">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group ">
        <label><h3>Message:</h3></label>
        <textarea name="message" class="form-control " rows="5" placeholder="Your message... " value="<?php echo $_POST['message']; ?>"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="col text-right">
        <div class="form-group ">
            <button class="button" type= "submit" name="submit" value="Submit">send</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
</div>
```

Another separate code where I tried using PHPMailer looks like this, which is basically copied from this link [getting custom php contact form to send email to exchange 365 account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43008851/getting-custom-php-contact-form-to-send-email-to-exchange-365-account)
:

```
<?php
    if ($_POST["submit"]) {

    include("PHPMailer-master/class.PHPMailer.php");

    $mail = new PHPMailer();
    
    $mail->IsSMTP();
    $mail->Host     = "localhost";
    $mail->SMTPAuth = false;
    $mail->Username = "mymail@outlook.com"; #or do i put my account for webhostapp?
    $mail->Password = "my_password_for_outlook";              
    
    $mail->From     = 'https://webpage.000webhostapp.com/';
    $mail->FromName = $_POST['name'];
    
    $mail->AddAddress('mymail@outlook.com'); 
    
    $mail->IsHTML(true);
    
    $mail->Subject  =  'Subject line goes here';
    
    $mail->Body     =  $_POST['message'];
    $mail->AltBody  =  $_POST['message'];
    
    $mail->Send();
}?>
```

[result after submitting form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y2Zev.png)

Comment: Please define ___not working___ just that is no help to us at all

Comment: Dont use `if (!$_POST['name']) {` instead do `if (! isset($_POST['name']) ) {`

Comment: not working meaning the email is not sent and I get errors

Comment: Well in that case it would be very useful if you showed US these errors **in the question** not in a comment. After all if you want help the more information you give us the more likely you are to get some useful help

Comment: as I said, I have tried using PHPMailer, but in this example I did not use it - I was trying so many things that I erased the code with PHPMailer but it was similar to the one I linked _ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17975204/trying-to-send-email-through-php-using-an-email-address-that-is-configured-on-mi

Comment: If, per chance, you get no errors then `$error` will never get defined and `if ($error) {` will produce a warning message